# Access the field value from IList in c#

Tags: c#, linq

I have a  `IList<T>` which has data and i want to access the field value from the IList.

I have written below code to get field value

```
IList<T> source;
source.FirstOrDefault().Field("ParentID")
```

I want to access ParentID field value.

But it is giving following error  while building the solution:

> "'T' does not contain a definition for 'Field' and no extension method 'Field' accepting a first argument of type 'T' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

I have added System.Xml, System.Xml.Linq and System.Collections.Generic assembly, but still it doesn't work. Can anybody help?

Comment: Did you define a class called T? If not you have to subsitute T for the class, with a ParentId-Property. In general T is just a placeholder in the documention.

Comment: No, I have not defined a class called T

Comment: User5590, to access property value first you need to initialize your variable `source`. Most probably `T` is representing a generic class, so you need to specify with what class you need to replace the `T`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is some generics 101.

Let's say you had a class named `Node`, which contained a property named `ParentID`.

```
public class Node 
{
    public int ParentId { get; set; }
}
```

Now you define a list of nodes. Basically an array of objects. In `List<T>` the `T` refers to the type of objects in your list. So you would define it as such:

```
IList<Node> source;
```

Then you would need to populate your list named `source`.

And then you could select the `ParentId` with the code you wrote.

```
source.FirstOrDefault().Field("ParentID")
```

Answer (score 0):

Cast source.FirstOrDefault() to the proper class for example : `((Employee)source.FirstOrDefault()).Field("ParentID")`

Comment: This is prone to cause InvalidCastException at runtime. He should rather use his generics properly.